# RuntimeException using a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, runtimeexception

I'm getting this weird error:

```
05-01 14:04:42.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3261): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I have seen a quite a number of posts but none of them worked for me. I am just trying to populate an array in to a `ListView`. It was working all fine, but I wanted to use some `SharedPreferences` in my code so I extended `PreferenceActivity` class. I guess since then this error started to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is pretty clear, if you extend `ListActivity`(`PreferenceActivity` extends `ListActivity` so has the same behaviour) and use a custom content view(with `setContentView()`), then in that layout file you must have a `ListView` element with the id:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

so the `ListActivity` knows on which `ListView` to bind the data.

Comment: Hey thanks Luksprog what do you mean byt a custom content view? can you give me an example please?

Comment: @rosesr I guess your using something like `setContentView(R.layout.a_layout_file)` in your activity. You should use the default `PreferenceActivity` and simply load your preferences(without setting the content view) file with the `addPreferencesFromResource` method.

Comment: I dont really get what you are saying here. what do you mean by "simply load your preferences(without setting the content view) file with the addPreferencesFromResource method"

Comment: @rosesr Check as an example this tutorial( http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences ) and see how that method is used.